# Arabic Fonts Disconnected in PDF file Using Pentaho 5.3

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

We are using Pentaho 5.3 and we are trying to generate arabic report. 
We installed all required fonts and stored in DB. From DB i am reading and printing in report. From preview it is coming correct and if we export to excel also coming correct. If we generate PDF Arabic letters are disconnected like below. We downloaded the adobe multi language support and tried getting the same space letters disconnected. Is there any setting in pentaho side to set?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of workaround, not perfect but it did a job for me.

1. Master report - set complex-text = true
2. set Encoding to UTF-8
3. all labels, text boxes and other text containing controls must have alignment set to left or right - center won't do (report is crashing if so) (!?)
4. As you said, use font that supports Arabic (Arial or so)